# getting only the exception ,not the entire stack trace

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-except, raise

I want to get only the exception message,not the entire stack trace.A toy example would be as follows:

```py
def div():
    try:
        print(0/0)
    except:
        raise Exception('Divide by zero,please check the input!!!')

def func1():
    try:
        div()
    except:
        raise Exception('Error in func11 try')
```

```py
func1()
```

**Expected output**

```
Exception: Divide by zero, please check the input!!!
Exception: Error in func11 try
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Below solution worked for me.

```py
import traceback
```

```py
def div():
    try:
        print(0/0)
    except:
        raise Exception('Divide by zero,please check the input!!!')
```

```py
def func2():
    try:
        div()
    except:
        raise Exception('Error in func 2!!!')
```

```py
def func1():
    exceptions=[]
    try:
        func2()
    except Exception as e:
        msg=traceback.format_exc()
        msg_list= msg.split('\n')
        [exceptions.append(line) for line in msg_list if line.startswith('Exception:')]
        return exceptions
```

```py
func1()
```

**output**

```
['Exception: Divide by zero,please check the input!!!',
 'Exception: Error in func 2!!!']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get the entire stack trace, you can try this:

```
def div():
    try:
        print(0/0)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: in my case I have deeply nested functions and the idea is to break out with a user-friendly message(without the stack trace). I found "traceback.format_exception_only" but not sure how to use it in my case.

Comment: This code should work in your case. If you want to add a user friendly line, then just add another print statement.

Comment: but it won't break out of nested function

Comment: Then add a break statement where needed

Comment: You may want to add `sys.exit()` in the `except` block if the aim is to have an otherwise similar effect to an uncaught exception apart from what is printed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Kairav Parekh works in your condition and it does not prints the entire stack trace, it only prints the error, which is user-friendly in most cases,

you only need to modify his code to match your requirements and you can put a break statement in except such as below,

```
def div():
    try:
        print(0/a)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break #break here
div()
```